# How to display UNICODE symbols in C programming

Tags: c

I need help on displaying Chess symbols in C program, how to do it?
I am using Code Blocks program to write c code and compile it
Any help is appreciated

Comment: In your C program you really don't have to do much, other than write the corresponding encoded Unicode character to `stdout` (like you do normally with e.g. `printf`). The problem is that the *displaying* of the Unicode characters depends on the terminal. For example the Windows old "DOS" terminal can't do it, but a modern Linux or macOS terminal can display many Unicode characters.

Comment: Can you write a code for one simple UNICODE symbol, just so i can see how it looks like

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: `printf("\u2654");` ***Could*** print the [white chess king](https://unicode-table.com/en/2654/). [This escape sequence reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape) could be helpful.

Comment: printf("\u2654"); does not print white chess king it prints something else like Oo0

Comment: Then it seems your terminal doesn't support it. It's not a fault with your program or with C.

Answer (score 0):

The most portable way to do this is to use the wide-character output functions in the standard library.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define WIDE_ORIENTED 1

int main(void)
{
  setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );
  fwide( stdout, WIDE_ORIENTED );
  fputws( L"♖♘♗♕♔♗♘♖\n", stdout );

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

On Windows, you can set the locale to `".1200"` to use UTF-16le in the console. Because Microsoft does not follow standards well, you might additionally need to call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`.

If you want to store Unicode strings as UTF-8, most operating systems will let you print them to the console.  On Linux, this requires setting the locale appropriately.  On Windows, it’s more complicated.  You want to put the console in UTF-8 mode with:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define CP_UTF8 65001

void init(void)
{
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
}
```

This will still not allow the locale functions (such as `isalpha()`) to work with UTF-8.  You would need to use another library to manipulate UTF-8 data, such as ICU.

Therefore, a cross-platform program that outputs UTF-8 should use `#ifdef` to detect whether it needs to compile the Windows-only initialization code, or else use a framework that takes care of this for you.